# Populate ComboBox based on filtered continuous form

Tags: ms-access, filter, combobox

I have  a table of products, batches and their test results. The user will be selecting a product to view all the tests. A continuous form is displayed with the filtered results.

What I would like is another custom filter in the form header that will list only those batches that are already displayed in the current filter set. For instance if they choose to look at test results for Product X, the form lists all the tests for Product X which may contain many batches...

I would like to have just those batches that are for Product X in the CBObox so the user can select it and see only that set of tests.

From what I have found on the web so far, they seem to be displaying ALL batches and not just those in the displayed record set.

Is this possible and thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer you received is incomplete, largely because you didn't share enough details in the question and because there are multiple ways of doing this.  If you set up your filter ComboBoxes correctly, you can have the RowSource queries refer directly to the filter controls to narrow the list of each successive filter ComboBox.  Minimal VBA might be required to refresh ComboBoxes and the form query after values are selected, but this likely require a couple lines of code.

Comment: Clearly define the relationships between products, test and batches.  Also describe the controls more accurately that you are trying to use.  Use technical descriptions rather than abstract explanations, for example:  "When the user selects a Product value from ComboBox `cboProducts`, I expect the batch values in the ComboBox `cboBatches` dropdown to be related only to the `cboProduct` value.  Overall I get the gist of what you want, but descriptions are confusing and seem to contradict regarding the displayed record set vs the displayed batches.

Comment: If you never get back to improving the question, you could at least search for `access cascade filter combo boxes` on the web.  There are a couple tutorials and other helps, and I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your database connected to sql server?   If so, filter using the where clause in a sql string.  If not vba is the answer to filtering based    on this results.   Do you have any pictures or sample code so I can help you out further. You could also set the record source of the combobox to the query with such filters applied.

Comment: thanks Joshua - I'm not on SQL - just stand-alone... I was hoping there was a simple structured way to do it, but it doesn't look like it... I will have to populate it with VBA - thats fine... thanks anyway...